# Write string to a stream using utf16 encoding

Tags: c#, string, utf-8, stream

My code:

```
        public static void DoStrumienia (string pString, Stream pStream)
        {
              if (pStream == null) throw new ArgumentNullException ();

              BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter (pStream);

              int rozmiar = pString.Length;
              bw.Write (rozmiar);

              for (int i = 0; i < rozmiar; i++)
              {
                    bw.Write (pString[i]);
              }

              bw.Flush ();
        }
```

It writes string to a stream, but it writes using UTF8 encoding.
How to it with UTF16?

Comment: Why are you writing one character at a time?

Comment: Because it's the only way what I know for now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode; 
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter (pStream, encoding);
```

[See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.bigendianunicode.aspx)

Comment: Why i should use Big Endian encoding? It doesnt make sense to me. I just fixed line: bw.Write (pString[i]); to bw.Write ((ushort)pString[i]); and maybe it will be works.

Comment: x86, so i use LE. Just casting to a USHORT make everything OK. Looks like BinaryWriter uses UTF8 encodinf for chars. So ushort prevents it, and all works ok. Anyway thank you for ur answer.

Comment: @zgnilec System.Text.Encoding.Unicode should be UTF-16 (little endian) encoding. Use that one if that's what you need.

Comment: Oh sorry, im little tired, didnt even looked u set stream to specyfic encoding :) Just thought u did conversion or smth:O need go to sleep, u got best answer, thank you.